# How to access JSON Nested arrays with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to access all brands and values for dropdown menu 
but I couldn't that with this way.

```
<select id="secim">
</select>

var data = [
        {
          "products": "Cars",
          "brands_values" : [
            {"brand":"fiat","value":1},
            {"brand":"bmw","value":2}
          ]
      }
      ];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#secim').append($('<option>', {
          value: item.brands_values.value,
          text: item.brands_values.brand
        }));
      });
```

How could I do? Thank you

Comment: This issue here is that `brands_values` is an array with multiple values. You would need an additional loop with your `$.each` to iterate over the elements within `brands_values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another loop for the brands:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "products": "Cars",
    "brands_values" : [
      {"brand":"fiat","value":1},
      {"brand":"bmw","value":2}
    ]
}];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if (item.brands_values) {
      item.brands_values.forEach(brands => {
        $('#secim').append($('<option>', {
          value: brands.value,
          text: brands.brand
        }));
      });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="secim">
</select>
```

Note: You may want to use native `.forEach` in that case, since it is enough. I had performance issues with `jQuery.each()` in the past so I avoid it whenever I can([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13095632/1267304)):

```
data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.brands_values) {
        item.brands_values.forEach(brands => {
            $('#secim').append($('<option>', {
                value: brands.value,
                text: brands.brand
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Works but why two loops ??

Comment: @ucnumara glad to help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  $.each(item.brands_values, function(j, brand){
    $('#secim').append($('<option>', {
      value: brand.value,
      text: brand.brand
    }));
  });
});
```

You need another iteration - of course the first "loop" is not very elegant, but this is due to the given data format.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3pL6n6pj/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over  brand values and not just data. So that you can acces each brand and value.

```js
  var data = [
        {
          "products": "Cars",
          "brands_values" : [
            {"brand":"fiat","value":1},
            {"brand":"bmw","value":2}
          ]
      }
      ];

  
  $.each(data[0].brands_values, function(i, item) {
       $('#secim').append($('<option>', {
              value: item.value,
              text: item.brand
            }));
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="secim">
</select>
```

Comment: IMO it's a good practice to check for `brands_values` value, it could be null. Also, if `data.length > 0` as you're hard-coding it's index.

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of `brand_values` from `data` by using a `#reduce()` function. Then pass it as `items` to your `$.each`.

See demo below:

```js
var data = [{
  "products": "Cars",
  "brands_values": [{
      "brand": "fiat",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "brand": "bmw",
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}];

var items = data.reduce(function(p,c){
  c.brands_values.forEach(function(e){
    p.push(e);
  });
  return p;
},[]);

$.each(items, function(i,item) {
  $('#secim').append($('<option>', {
    value: item.value,
    text: item.brand
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="secim"></select>
```